# Result of one xslt transformation is input for the another one

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I'm a beginner in xslt , so don't mind me asking the basic questions. I would like to use the result of the first transformation level as an input for the another one. The input for the first transformation is a target.xml file, which includes subscribers ("aries","cas"...):

```
<subscription-table>
        <subscriber name="aries" useZipXfer="yes" usePubMed="no">
            <ftp server="dummy.url1.com" port="21" remotedir="/XXXXXXX" userid="XXXXXXX" password="XXXXXXXXX" binary="yes" passive="no"/>
            <notify-success>
                <mail mailhost="smtprelayptc1.test.net" mailport="25" subject="MRCS-PS HEADER UPDATE - PAP">
                    <from address="success1.from@mail.com"/>
                    <to address="success1.to@mail.com"/>
                </mail>
            </notify-success>
            <notify-failure>
                <mail mailhost="smtprelayptc1.test.net" mailport="25" subject="MRCS-PS HEADER UPDATE - PAP">
                    <from address="failure1.from@mail.com"/>
                    <to address="failure1.to@mail.com"/>
                </mail>
            </notify-failure>
        </subscriber>
        <subscriber name="cas" useZipXfer="no" usePubMed="yes" sendPromote="no">
            <ftp server="dummy.url2.com" port="21" remotedir="/YYYYYYY" userid="YYYYYYY" password="YYYYYYYYY" binary="yes" passive="no"/>
            <notify-success>
                <mail mailhost="smtprelayptc1.test.net" mailport="25" subject="MRCS-PS HEADER UPDATE - PAP">
                    <from address="success2.from@mail.com"/>
                    <to address="success2.to@mail.com"/>
                </mail>
            </notify-success>
            <notify-failure>
                <mail mailhost="smtprelayptc1.test.net" mailport="25" subject="MRCS-PS HEADER UPDATE - PAP">
                    <from address="failure2.from@mail.com"/>
                    <to address="failure2.to@mail.com"/>
                </mail>
            </notify-failure>
        </subscriber>
</subscription-table>
```

Each subscriber has its own file (aries_subscriptions.xml, cas_subscriptions.xml...). The subscriptions files include journals. For example, aries_subscriptions.xml is:

```
<subscription>
     <database status="update" name="ovftdb">        
         <journal status="*" name="00002030" >
             <issue status="new" pubdate="01/01/2004" name="*" an="99999999-999999999-99999" >
                 <header/>
             </issue>
         </journal>      
         <journal status="*" name="00000374" >
             <issue status="new" pubdate="01/01/2004" name="*" an="99999999-999999999-99999" >
                 <header/>
             </issue>
         </journal>      
         <journal status="*" name="00000372" >
             <issue status="new" pubdate="01/01/2004" name="*" an="99999999-999999999-99999" >
                 <header/>
             </issue>
         </journal>
...
```

I need to generate the third file, lookup.xml, which can have repeated journals, depend on subscribers (subscriber is in the attribute "identifier"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<journals xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <journal name="00002030">
            <target identifier="aries" pubdate="01/01/2004">
                <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
            </target>
        </journal>
        <journal name="00000372">
            <target identifier="aries" pubdate="01/01/2004">
                <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
            </target>
        </journal>
        <journal name="00002030">
            <target identifier="cas" pubdate="01/01/2004">
                <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
            </target>
        </journal>
        <journal name="00000372">
            <target identifier="cas" pubdate="01/01/2004">
                <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
            </target>
        </journal>
    </journals>
```

I would like to use xslt code, which creates repeated journals, and generate the document that have unique journals, with all its nested subscribers. The desired document would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<journals xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    <journal name="00002030">
       <target identifier="aries" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
       </target>
       <target identifier="cas" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
       </target>
    </journal>
    <journal name="00000372">
       <target identifier="aries" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
       </target>
       <target identifier="cas" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
       </target>
    </journal>  
</journals>
```

The first part of xslt, which creates duplicated journals, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"      
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsl saxon xlink">


    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />    

    <xsl:include href="utilities.xsl" />
    <xsl:include href="assetTargetToLookupRemoveDuplicates.xsl"/>

    <xsl:variable name="inputFolderAndFile">
        <xsl:call-template
            name="getValuesBeforeAndAfterLastOccurance">
            <xsl:with-param name="inputString"
                select="string(base-uri(.))" />
            <xsl:with-param name="char" select="'/'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="inputFolderPath"
        select="substring-before($inputFolderAndFile, '*')" />
    <xsl:variable name="inputFile"
        select="substring-after($inputFolderAndFile, '*')" />
    <xsl:variable name="tokens"
        select="tokenize($inputFile,'\.')" />
    <xsl:variable name="baseFileName"
        select="string-join($tokens[not(.=$tokens[last()])], '.')" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | * | comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="package"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="package">
        <xsl:copy/> 
    </xsl:template>     

    <xsl:template match="/" mode="package">
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" href="lookup.xml">
            <xsl:variable name="initialOutput">             
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="package"/>               
            </xsl:variable>                                             
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$initialOutput" mode="remove-duplicates"/>                        
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="subscriber" mode="package">
        <xsl:variable name="subscriberName" select="document(concat($inputFolderPath, '/', @name,'_subscriptions.xml'))" />
        <xsl:element name="journals" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">      
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$subscriberName" mode="journal-processing"/>
        </xsl:element>      
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="journal" mode="journal-processing">
        <xsl:variable name="journalName" select="@name" />
        <xsl:variable name="journalPubDate" select="issue/@pubdate" />
        <xsl:variable name="subscriberNameFromDoc" select="substring-before(tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()], '_subscriptions')" />

        <xsl:element name="journal">
            <xsl:attribute name="name" select="$journalName"/>
            <xsl:element name="target">
                <xsl:attribute name="identifier" select="$subscriberNameFromDoc"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="pubdate" select="$journalPubDate"/>
                <xsl:element name="targetLink">                                                            
                    <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])</xsl:attribute>                    
                    <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href" select="targets.xml#//descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc']"/> -->
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to use $initialOutput variable to provide the result of the first transformation to the next one. In the second transformation, assetTargetToLookupRemoveDuplicates.xsl, I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xlink xs xsl saxon"
    version="2.0">


    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/" mode="remove-duplicates">       
        <xsl:apply-templates select="journals" mode="remove-duplicates"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="journals" mode="remove-duplicates">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="journal" group-by="@name">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/target"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second transformation doesn't transform the duplicate journals to unique ones. The result of the whole process is the document with duplicate journals. The result is, again:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<journals xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <journal name="00002030">
            <target identifier="aries" pubdate="01/01/2004">
                <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
            </target>
        </journal>
        <journal name="00000372">
            <target identifier="aries" pubdate="01/01/2004">
                <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
            </target>
        </journal>
        <journal name="00002030">
            <target identifier="cas" pubdate="01/01/2004">
                <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
            </target>
        </journal>
        <journal name="00000372">
            <target identifier="cas" pubdate="01/01/2004">
                <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
            </target>
        </journal>
    </journals>
```

Could you please help me to find out why the second transformation works that way? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Which version of Saxon do you use? Shouldn't you make the mode `package` the initial mode?

Comment: I am not sure that I got my Saxon version on the right way. I think my Saxon version is SaxonEE9-6-0-10J, and I am using saxon9ee.jar. I have tried to change the mode "package" to the initial mode, but it doesn't help, sorry. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin's comments and help, I finally fixed the solution. The following code does the things I described in my question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"      
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"      
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsl saxon xlink">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"
        indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" saxon:character-representation="entity" />

    <xsl:include href="utilities.xsl" />    

    <xsl:variable name="inputFolderAndFile">
        <xsl:call-template
            name="getValuesBeforeAndAfterLastOccurance">
            <xsl:with-param name="inputString"
                select="string(base-uri(.))" />
            <xsl:with-param name="char" select="'/'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="inputFolderPath"
        select="substring-before($inputFolderAndFile, '*')" />
    <xsl:variable name="inputFile"
        select="substring-after($inputFolderAndFile, '*')" />
    <xsl:variable name="tokens"
        select="tokenize($inputFile,'\.')" />
    <xsl:variable name="baseFileName"
        select="string-join($tokens[not(.=$tokens[last()])], '.')" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | * | comment() | processing-instruction()">    
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" >
        <xsl:copy/> 
    </xsl:template>     


    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <xsl:variable name="initialOutput">
            <xsl:element name="journals">
                <xsl:namespace name="xlink" select="'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'"/>       
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>          
        </xsl:variable>                                                                     
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$initialOutput" mode="remove-duplicates"/>  
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="subscriber">       
        <xsl:variable name="subscriberName" select="document(concat($inputFolderPath, '/', @name,'_subscriptions.xml'))" />     
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$subscriberName" mode="journal-processing"/>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="journal" mode="journal-processing">
        <xsl:variable name="journalName" select="@name" />
        <xsl:variable name="journalPubDate" select="issue/@pubdate" />
        <xsl:variable name="subscriberNameFromDoc" select="substring-before(tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()], '_subscriptions')" />

        <xsl:element name="journal">
            <xsl:attribute name="name" select="$journalName"/>
            <xsl:element name="target">
                <xsl:attribute name="identifier" select="$subscriberNameFromDoc"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="pubdate" select="$journalPubDate"/>
                <xsl:element name="targetLink" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                                        <xsl:variable name="apostrophe">'</xsl:variable>                
                    <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href" select="concat('targets.xml','#','xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name=',$apostrophe,$subscriberNameFromDoc,$apostrophe,'])')"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="/" mode="remove-duplicates">           
        <xsl:apply-templates select="journals" mode="remove-duplicates"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="journals" mode="remove-duplicates">                    
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="journal" group-by="@name">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/target"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rewrite

```
<xsl:template match="/" mode="package">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" href="lookup.xml">
        <xsl:variable name="initialOutput">             
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="package"/>               
        </xsl:variable>                                             
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$initialOutput" mode="remove-duplicates"/>                        
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

as

```
<xsl:variable name="initialOutput">             
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="package"/>               
</xsl:variable> 

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" href="lookup.xml">                                   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$initialOutput" mode="remove-duplicates"/>                        
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Martin,thank you very much for your time and attention. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The result of the final process is an empty document.When I changed again <xsl:template match="/"> to <xsl:template match="/" mode="package"> I got the result without removed duplicates. I have also tried to change the mode "package" to initial mode, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @nean0502, at one point your code has `<xsl:element name="journals" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` so it creates a `journals` element in the XLink namespace. All your XSLT templates seem to process elements in no namespace. So namespace differences are one mayor reason why you might not get any output. You might need to output intermediary results for debugging purposes to check you really have the intermediary result your second mode expects.

Comment: Thank you very much again Martin. I will do my best to resolve this.

Comment: I have understood that my template "remove-duplicates" is not applied at all for some reason.